# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 50176 into shape (7,7,512)

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, numpy-ndarray, tf.keras, vgg-net

I am trying to train a model(by incorporating vgg16 in the encoder network of autoencoder) but the input shape requirement is(7,7,512) for the decoder network. While my data is in grayscale vgg16 requires 3 color channels so for this i've copied the data array thrice to do so which is not the problem. The problem is here where i'm trying to reshape the array which is not happening and giving me errors. code:
train_X and train_Y are the list containing training datasets of size 5k each with dims=224,224 and are in gray scale.
After this I've done->

```
train_X=np.array(X_train)
train_Y=np.array(Y_train)

train_X=train_X/255.0
train_Y=train_Y/255.0

print(train_Y.shape)  
train_Y = np.repeat(train_Y[..., np.newaxis], 3, -1)
print(train_Y.shape) 

#same for train_X
 
print(train_Y.shape)
print(train_X.shape)
```

output->(5000, 224, 224, 3) &
(5000, 224, 224, 3)

```
trainx = train_X.reshape((7,7,512))
```

**error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 50176 into shape (7,7,512)**

network I'm trying to train:

```
#encoder
encoder_input = Input(shape=(7,7,512,))
#Decoder
decoder_output = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_input)
decoder_output = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
model = Model(inputs=encoder_input, outputs=decoder_output)
```

Encoder is vgg16.
model summary:

```
Metal device set to: Apple M1 Pro
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 block1_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
                                                                 
 block1_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
                                                                 
 block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
                                                                 
 block2_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
                                                                 
 block2_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
                                                                 
 block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 block3_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
                                                                 
 block3_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
                                                                 
 block4_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
                                                                 
 block4_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
                                                                 
 block5_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,688
Trainable params: 14,714,688
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

have tries several hacks but i'm not able to get through this problem.

Comment: This is a mess. You say you have 5000 elements but the comment in the code says 64. Then your reshape doesn't include the number of elements at all (you would need to reshape to `(5000, 7, 7, 512)` or something like that). But the number of elements listed in the error corresponds to `2*7*7*512`, indicating you only have 2 elements. So which one is it?

Comment: Please ignore the comment the output is 5k, 224, 224,3 @xdurch0

Comment: 50176 is 224*224

Comment: the dataset is grayscale it shows 3 channels due to np.repeat step as you can see @xdurch0

Comment: Why do you want to use a network with an input shape (7, 7, 512), if the images are of shape (224, 224)?

Comment: @YScharf the network requires it to be that way if you see the model summary..the last layes otput shape is like that(pretrained vgg16) thats to be fed into decoder network

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `VGG_16` `pretrained model` as an `encoder network`.
If I understand correctly you are using the encoder and decoder to denoise images.
The encoder is the pretrained `VGG_16` model and the decoder is a model (give them different names) you are training using `train_y` as your ground truth for denoised images.

Feed the images into the encoder network.

`trainx_encoded = model.predict(train_x)`

Check the `model_decoder` for it's `output-shape` and make sure it matches the `train_y` shape.

```
for layer in model_decoder.layers:
    print(layer.output_shape)
```

Running this myself informed me that the output layer has a shape of (224,224,2).
You have two options:

1. Change the decoder network to have an output shape of (224,224,3) by updating the last conv layer to have 3 channels.

`decoder_output = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same')(decoder_output)`

2. Leave the train_y data as grayscale with one channel and update the above layer to have on e channel.

`decoder_output = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same')(decoder_output)`

Then use the encoded data as training data for the second model.

`model_decoder.fit(trainx_encoded , train_y)`

Comment: wouldnt this show a error while model.fit now that the dims of x and y would again be differentr?

Comment: Please explain again what `train_x` and `train_y` represent.

Comment: ok so trainx contains noisy images and trainy has actual expected denoised images  @YScharf

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot it isn't showing me errors like before and has started with training i understood where i was going wrong all thanks to you!  but the problem here is that the loss doesnt changes along with accuracy. remains same for all the epochs..T_T...

Comment: Thanks for the loud SHOUTOUT ;). Another angle you could try: Use just the first few layers of the VGG-model, say up to block3_conv3 . This way you don't lose the high-level features of the original image. You can also try using 1x1 conv layer to reduce number of channels in the first layers of the decoder network.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all the suggestions , trying out what all you've advised :)))